# How to extract a character from a string in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable T in he form YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00, where YYYY is the 4-digit year, MM is the month and HH is the hour.
I want to extract individual fields.
Firstly when I do:

```
print("T = ",T)
```

I get

```
T =  [b'2' b'0' b'1' b'9' b'-' b'0' b'6' b'-' b'0' b'2' b'_' b'0' b'0' b':' b'0' b'0' b':' b'0' b'0']
```

In python2.7 I do:

```
myList = list(T[0:4])
yr = "".join(myList)

myList = list(T[5:7])
mn = "".join(myList)

myList = list(T[8:10])
dy = "".join(myList)

myList = list(T[11:13])
hr = "".join(myList)
```

These lines give me the digits.

However in python 3.7 I get stuck at the very first field

```
myList = list(T[0:4])
print("myList = ",myList) -> myList =  [b'2', b'0', b'1', b'9']
yr = "".join(myList)
```

gives error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.bytes_ found
```

But

```
yr = b"".join(myList)
```

gives

```
print("yr = ",yr) -> yr =  b'2019'
```

From here I am not able to extract the year digits.

```
print("yr = ",yr[0:3]) -> yr =  b'201'

print("yr = ",yr[1:4]) -> yr =  b'019'
```

I have also tried

```
newyr = yr.replace("b", "")
```

and
         p = yr.index("b")  # find position of the letter "b"
    TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

All these do not work.

How do I get rid of the b and keep the year digits. Since python 2.7 will no longer be maintained from 2020, I need my code to work in python 3.x

Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Try: `yr = "".join(map(str, list))`

Comment: You haven't given the definition of `T`, and a bunch of your code is not valid Python syntax. Please edit and fix that. Also for something like `myList = list(T[0:4]); yr = "".join(myList)`, why not just use `yr = "".join(T[0:4])`?

Comment: @wjandrea sounds like Python 2.7 `join` can handle `numpy.bytes_` but Python 3.x can't without converting it into a string first.

Comment: @alfasin that would make sense

Comment: I think fundamentally, you need to learn about `str` vs `bytes` in Python 3, and how that's different to Python 2. This might be a good place to start: [Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit - What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit). Basically in 2, `str` = `bytes`, but in 3, `str` = `unicode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the text.

```
def get_year(text):
    text = text.decode("utf-8")

    year = text.split('-')[0]

    return text, year

get_year(T[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @Luca for the excellent answer. And thank you all for your time and the good advices. I have learnt a lot from this. This also works: nyr=yr.decode('ascii').strip().